# Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu MATE: Kernel panic not syncing - init_resize.sh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, kernel-panic, mate

Despite Google I found no solution to my problem. During booting a Kernel panic happens.

- Raspberry Pi: Model B
- SD Card: SanDisk Extreme 8GB and Transcend SD HC 16GB
- OS: [Ubuntu MATE for Raspberry Pi 16.04](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/)
- Checksum already checked
- Image to SD card written by Win32 Disk Image 1.0

[image: Screenshot boot up!]

Comment: Is this a fresh installation of Raspbian? Or you are using your own version of Ubuntu Mate?

Comment: a fresh installation of the official Ubuntu Mate image: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

Comment: Can you confirm if you got Raspberry Pi 2 or Raspberry Pi 3? (since Ubuntu Mate page seems to indicate it is only for 2, and 3). I personally have Raspberry Pi 1 Model B+ (the earliest version) and I'd expect Ubuntu Mate will not run on mine..

Comment: Yes you are right! I didn't consider the model at all! Thank you for your hint!